# Inserting a closed section

Tags: notebooks, cells

Is there a way to insert a closed section? I know in .m files if you do `(* ::Section::Closed:: *)` and open the .m file using system editor, a closed section will be displayed. Is there a way to create a closed section in the notebook while using `CreateDocument[]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, but a notebook has a more involved structure than the .m files you have investigated. The code to do what you want isn't very complicated, though:

```
CreateDocument[{CellGroup[{
    TextCell["section", "Section"],
    TextCell["content", "Text"]
    }, Closed]}]
```